# 'How to ask questions' guidelines are not visible on android mobile page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, mobile-web

The desktop page version of Stack Exchange sites has very clear 'how to ask' guidelines on the right of screen but the same  are not seen when a user is ready to type in their question on the **android mobile page version** (not the Stack Exchange android app but the browser page.) See image below.

Since a huge number of users are accessing the internet through android smartphones, including these guidelines on the mobile page and asking new users to read them before posting their first question might be useful to familiarize new users with site guidelines and help them avoid asking a low-quality or otherwise off-topic question.

[image]

---

I later found this excellent suggestion posted by a member last year at English.meta.SE [Can a placeholder text be added to the question body box?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7563/can-a-placeholder-text-be-added-to-the-question-body-box)

Comment: ah you got a big mobile!!

Comment: @SagarV Mobile devices from the smallest android phones upward (to the largest tablets) have become the preferred portal to the internet in the facebook/twitter age. This is just a small 5.7 inch screen and I seen my friends and neighbors here in South India use bigger screens! We would like the 'how to ask' guidelines to appear here to help brand-new users.

Comment: +1'ed.  The reason is the screen doesn't have enough space to all those. Better provide a page with guidelines(it is already there for first time ask in private beta). with a proceed button to ask form. I didn't see large number of people using huge screen in south india. The maximum is 5.7" or 5.5" (in my place, Kerala)

Comment: @Sagar V good idea to provide a prominent link button; thanks for upvote; 5 to 5.7 inch screen is more convenient to view SE than 7 inch tablet. The guidelines could appear in a popup box or even in light gray 'holograph' style over the white space in the ask box; ask the reader to click 'I have read and understood' box and it disappears, allowing the new user to type his question. It is important because at least at English.SE too many new users have been asking off-topic questions without reading the guidelines, mainly because they must be using mobile devices.

Comment: @Jaideep Khare yes indeed! Even I am using jio 4G only, and it is *so good.*

Comment: I later found this excellent suggestion posted last year by a member at English.meta.SE https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7563/can-a-placeholder-text-be-added-to-the-question-body-box